# How to zip all my Magento 2 files on my server?

Tags: magento2, server-setup, zip

How could I zip all my Magento files excluding non-required to a local setup?

I usually run this command to get all the files. But, it takes too long and the files are too heavy.

```
zip -r magento2.zip ./*
```

Do you have any suggestions to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude the non-versioned folders and you can use **-9** to compress all the files included in your ZIP.

```
zip -r -9 magento2.zip ./* \
-x "vendor/*" \
-x "generated/*" \
-x "pub/static/*" \
-x "pub/media/*" \
-x "var/*" \
-x "pub/wp/wp-content/uploads/*" \
-x "node_modules/*"
```

To compress your media folder too, I recommend using:

```
n98-magerun.phar media:dump media.zip
```

Generated CSS, JS and product image cache you can pass the option **--strip**

Answer (score 0):

To create compressed archive named data.zip of data folder in the current directory, run:
zip -r data.zip data/